# Range sliders in android

Tags: android, slider

Hi I have to make a range slider and I found a very good example. I have taken a reference of slider from

http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=5300044

In this from where I will get this library?

```
com.att.widgets.lib.control.SliderControl
```

If someone has used this then let me know.

Please suggest..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could directly download the eclipse project from [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/UNvlbTpq/DualKnobSlider.html)